# How-to displaying user friendly names for groups and service principals in Azure Analysis Services

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-analysis-services

We switched to Azure Analysis Services earlier this year. After migrating all components and making it work with a Managed Instance and Power BI Service, we have arrived at finetuning stage.

I noticed that groups and Service Principals are display as objectId@tenantId in the Membership overview in Role Properties. I would like to have a more userfriendly reference such as the DisplayName, MailNickName or as for the user class the UserPrincipalName.

[image: Role Properties - Membership]

It is rather cumbersome to deceipher the object id with PowerShell / Azure portal to check whether the right group has access.

Is this possible by changing a property for a AAD Group / Service Principal?
Or is this something that should be addressed in SSMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this, is by changing the 'type' of your Azure Active Directory group from 'Security' to 'Mail enabled security' by populating an e-mail address.

[See example screenshot of Azure portal here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pk3d.png)

This does not need to be a working e-mail address mailing list or inbox.

In our case the Email field now contains a value xxx@yyy.onmicrosoft.com which is visible in Azure Analysis Services in the Membership page in Role Properties, instead of the objectId@tenantId value.

[See example screenshot of SSMS here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnTfF.png)

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible by changing a property for a AAD Group / Service Principal?

I am afraid it is impossible, the format `obj:objectId@tenantId` is fixed.

> Or is this something that should be addressed in SSMS?

Maybe, but as I know, SSMS does not support this currently.